# CodeIgniter set multiple connections for mssql dbs?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I am so sick with the CI framework already, because I can't even set multiple connection for MSSQL Server. I've found a forum where had been described how to set multiple connection, but it didn't work well for me - the mssql_query statement throws an error that *the link identifier is not the MSSQL-Link resource etc*.
I've done something like this:

1) set the database.php - database configuration file:

```
$active_group = 'suburb';
$active_record = FALSE;

$db['suburb']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$db['suburb']['username'] = 'XXXX';
$db['suburb']['password'] = 'XXXXXXX';
$db['suburb']['database'] = 'XXXXXXX';
$db['suburb']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['suburb']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['suburb']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['suburb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['suburb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['suburb']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['suburb']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['suburb']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['suburb']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['suburb']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['suburb']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = FALSE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['default']['username'] = 'XXXX';
$db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['database'] = 'XXXXXX';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

2) call the load dbs function:

```
$this->suburbDb = $this->load->database('suburb', true);
```

3) created the query:

```
$res = mssql_query("
  SELECT TOP 100 ID 
  FROM Table", $this->suburbDb);
```

Comment: Watching your conig, you have 2 active groups. which is not possible, you need to remove the second set $active_group,$active_record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are mixing CI and php native mssql driver.

`$this->suburbDb` is CI database object not link identifier:

```
$this->suburbDb->query('SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM Table');
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

OR if you really need then

```
mssql_query($query, $this->suburbDb->conn_id)
```

Comment: Interesting point $this->suburbDb is CI database object not link identifier, but may I use, somehow, standart sql query functions in php like mssql_query($query, $link);?

Comment: sure, you can use `mssql_query($query, $this->suburbDb->conn_id)`

Comment: You've got everything U could from me - I'm about points, accept of an answer and comment up, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize both connections with something like this

```
$this->suburb  = $this->load->database('suburb', TRUE);
$this->default = $this->load->database('default', TRUE); 

$this->db; //<--- houlds the DEFAULT loaded from config file. can only be one

$query = $this->suburb->query('SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM Table');

foreach( $query->result() as $row)
{
....
}
```

Should be something like that.

PS. check the codeigniter guide : [CodeIgniter Guide Database Connection](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)

[ EDIT : WITHOUT ACTIVE RECORD ]

after making the connection mssql should be possible to execute by itself like this :

```
// Send a select query to MSSQL
$query = mssql_query('SELECT TOP 100 ID FROM Table', $this->suburb );

// Check if there were any records
if (!mssql_num_rows($query)) {
    echo 'No records found';
} else {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['username'], PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// Free the query result
mssql_free_result($query);
```

Comment: Your answer is quite good but I don't want to use active records, may be U know how to use standart sintax like mssql_query($query, $link);?

Comment: try this after making the connection : 

     $version = mssql_query('SELECT @@VERSION');
     $row = mssql_fetch_array($version);

     echo $row[0];

     // Clean up
     mssql_free_result($version);